# Converter encoding CP850 para UTF8

Tags: c#, .net, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8

Tenho um BD Paradox que me retorna a seguinte string após uma consulta em uma tabela do setor que um determinado trabalhador fica: ManutenþÒo ElÚtrica. Na verdade deveria ser Manutenção Elétrica. Eu preciso retornar essa string para um browser.

Pelas minhas pesquisas, essa é uma codificação CP850 que preciso converter para o UTF-8, que é a codificação que geralmente se usa. Vi isso no link:

http://codepage-encoding.online-domain-tools.com/run/?tool=codepage&inputType=frm-text&text=Manuten%C3%BE%C3%92o%20El%C3%9Atrica&sourceCodepage=UTF-8&targetCodepage=CP850&convert=do

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte no C#:

```
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
Encoding cp = Encoding.GetEncoding(850);

byte[] cpBytes = cp.GetBytes(identifColaborador.setor);//aqui já vem como ManutenþÒo ElÚtrica 

byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(cp, utf8, cpBytes);
string msg = utf8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

Mas infelizmente não estou obtendo sucesso. Ainda retorna na string msg ManutenþÒo ElÚtrica

Onde posso estar errando?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu código não tem efeito nenhum na string retornada, pois ele está partindo de uma representação abstrata e chegando numa outra representação abstrata. Não sei se consigo explicar, vou tentar dar um exemplo fictício:

```
// Letra (code point)          Encoding A            Encoding B
// a                           0xAA 0xBB             0xCC
// b                           0xDD                  0xEE oxFF

string original = "aaba";

byte[] aBytes = a.GetBytes(original);
// aBytes = [0xAA 0xBB 0xAA 0xBB 0xCC 0xAA 0xBB]

byte[] bBytes = Encoding.Convert(a, b, aBytes);
// bBytes = [0xDD 0xDD 0xEE oxFF 0xDD ]

string msg = b.GetString(bBytes);
// msg = "aaba"
```

Qualquer string que passar por esse processo vai continuar inalterada (a menos que um dos encodings não dê suporte a algum dos caracteres). Para corrigir o seu problema, você precisa que o conteúdo da string `identifColaborador.setor` seja interpretado no encoding correto **antes de virar string**.

Caso isso não seja possível, e você tenha que trabalhar com a string já na sua representação abstrata, então o correto é tentar interpretar os bytes que compõem a string **sem fazer conversão**. Ou seja, simplesmente pegue `aBytes` e transforme em string de acordo com o encoding B. O código abaixo [funcionou no ideone](https://ideone.com/tS4gTj), mas talvez não funcione no seu sistema, portanto experimente diferentes valores para `seuEncoding` (UTF-8, UTF-16, Cp1252, ISO-Latin, `Encoding.Default`, etc).

```
Encoding seuEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Cp1252");
Encoding cp850 = Encoding.GetEncoding(850);

byte[] cpBytes = cp850.GetBytes("ManutenþÒo ElÚtrica");
string msg = seuEncoding.GetString(cpBytes);
```

Comment: Marcelo, obrigado pela dica. Apenas precisei trocar Cp1252 por Windows-1252 e tudo rodou certinho...Vlw